# Power BI DAX - Measure to change name of row value

Tags: powerbi, dax, rows, selectedvalue, slicers

I need some help creating a measure to change the name of "FROM_USER" in the slicer here.
I think I need to use the function SELECTEDVALUE, but I have not managed to get it working.
So, the column has only two values, CRAWLER and FROM_USER.
Any suggestions would be helpful!

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pExhq.png)

Comment: Hei Simen. Change the value to what? Something dynamic? Measures cannot be used as slicers, but some functionality can be leveraged with some techniques involving adding extra tables with relationships to the column you want to amend.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow .... your question not enough quality, please read help center, section `how to ask good question` here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you can get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Measures can't be used as slicer values. If you want the column values to be changed and yet to be used in a slicer, you need to create a calculate column to change that.

```
Column = IF('Table'[Column1]="FROM_USER","desiredValue","CRAWLER")
```

If you are really keen on using a measure to slice, you need to build a disconnected table and follow the method described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHiCE1N0XHE&t=15s). But the performance will take a hit depending on how complex your data model and calculations are.